# when i try to go run main.go i get cgo: exec gcc: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, ubuntu

i am trying to run my go files but i get this error

i am using Ubuntu

```
#github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
cgo: exec gcc: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have fixed this error**

this error tell you don't has a gcc files in  PATH
so you must install it

how to install it:

```
1- sudo apt-get  build-dep  gcc
2- sudo apt-get  install  build-essential
```

check if gcc is instald or not by

```
3-  gcc --version
```

and then run your project